# 画面更新(リロード)するとhomeディレクトリ以外のCSSが反映されない場合の解決方法がわからないです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

今Railsでブログを作成しています。

全部のページ表示は最初正常に反映されるのですが、画面をリロードすると
CSSが反映されません。CSSが反映されなくなる要因はURLの階層が一段深いです。
ページのレイアウトはapplication.html.erbです。
階層が深くなってもCSSが反映されるようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

画面更新してもCSSは正常に反映される (views/home/index)
http://localhost:3000/index

画面更新すると反映されなくなる (views/images/index)
http://localhost:3000/images/index

因みにChromeの検証で確認してみると
「GET http://localhost:3000/images/assets/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)」
と出てしまいます。

すみませんが、解決方法がわかる方がいましたら教えていただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

追記：ファイルの階層は以下になります。

**app**---**assets**---**stylesheets**---**style.css**
ｌ
ｌ_____**views**---**home**
　　　　　ｌ__**images**

```
application.html.erb(共通レイアウト、ヘッド部分)
```

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Labs - Design Studio">
<meta name="keywords" content="lab, onepage, creative, html">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,500,700|Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/flaticon.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/owl.carousel.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css"/>
```

**body**内で**yield**で各々のページ対応させているのですが、imagesフォルダ配下にあるファイル
に飛ぶと、最初は正常に動作しますが、リロードするとＣＳＳが反映されなくなります。(homeフォルダ配下は正常に動きます。)

URLの階層が深くなる場合、なにかapplication.html.erb側に追記しなければいけないのでしょうか。

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/images/assets/style.cssでNotFoundのエラーになるのは、style.cssファイルが想定しているフォルダーにないからだと思います。各フォルダーにどんなcssファイルが置かれているのかを示してください。また、それらを使っているhtmlファイルの内容も質問に追加してください。そうした情報が無いのに原因が判る(見たこともないファイルの配置と内容が想像できる)人は居ませんからね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。情報不足でもうしわけありません。追記しました。